# How to pass through params to Jenkins job?

Tags: git, jenkins

Job A triggers 2 parallel parametrized jobs B.

**Job A:**

```
stage('Build and Deploy') {
    branch = "${BRANCH}"

    def builds = [:]
    builds["A"] = {
        build job: 'job-A',parameters: [
            string(name: 'module', value: "A"),
            string(name: 'BRANCH', value: ${BRANCH}),
            string(name: 'AUTO_DEPLOY', value: 'true') ],  quietPeriod: 2
        }
    builds["B"] = {
        build job: 'job-B', parameters: [
            string(name: 'module', value: "A"),
            string(name: 'BRANCH', value: ${BRANCH}),
            string(name: 'AUTO_DEPLOY', value: 'true')], quietPeriod: 2
    }
    parallel builds

    build job: "deploy-job-A", parameters: [string(name: 'AUTO_DEPLOY', value: "true")], wait: false
    build job: "deploy-job-B", parameters: [string(name: 'AUTO_DEPLOY', value: "true")], wait: false

}
```

It has a choice parameter `BRANCH` that has names of branches that need to be passed to job B. Another choice parameter is `AUTO_DEPLOY` that is passed to job B and job B must pass it down the chain because it is needed in job C.

**Job B**

```
node {
    stage("Build job-${module} image") {
        branch = "${env.BRANCH}"
        checkout scm
        buildVersion= readFile('job.version').trim() + ".${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        // stuff
        build job: "deploy-${JOB_NAME}", parameters: [
                string(name: 'buildVersion', value: buildVersion),
                string(name: 'AUTO_DEPLOY', value: ${env.AUTO_DEPLOY})], wait: false
    }
}
```

**Job C:**

```
script {
    def deployVersion = "${image}".substring("${image}".lastIndexOf(':') + 1)
    currentBuild.description = "${deployVersion}"
}

stage('Checkout') {
    node {
        checkout scm
    }
}
stage('Deploy prelive') {
    try {
        milestone 1
        if (${env.AUTO_DEPLOY} != 'true') {
            input message: "Deploy ${image} to prelive?"
        }
        milestone 2
        // stuff
}
```

**UPDATE:**

job A throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

most likely it cannot resolve param `string(name: 'BRANCH', value: ${BRANCH})`

Answer (score 0):

It cannot resolve ${BRANCH} because that is a string interpolation... without a string. Surround it with quotes and it should work:

```
string(name: 'BRANCH', value: "${BRANCH}")
```

Edit:

I'm assuming BRANCH is a string variable. In that case you could just omit the $

```
string(name: 'BRANCH', value: BRANCH)
```

if it's not, you could use the "branch" variable you're declaring at the top.